# Docker function - error response OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker

I'm working with the book `Docker in action` and I'm trying to work with Docker.

When I run the following commands:

```
docker run --name export-test \
dockerinaction/ch7_packed:latest ./echo For Export
docker export --output contents.tar export-test 
docker rm export-test
tar -tf contents.tar
the console returns me:
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
\"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I tried to find a solution, but could not find one that works. I have rebooted `Docker` and it is still doesn't works!

Comment: seems to be a common issue. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are running an old version of Linux, or it is just a compatibility issue. Also, this error may indicate an issue with the docker daemon itself, not the container you are trying to run. Try to delete all containers, and restart the daemon. Also try to clean up the docker networks.

Please see [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35972) detailed explanation about the problem, and [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) are the OS requirements for the Docker to work properly. In addition, you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816702/docker-error-response-from-daemon-oci-runtime-create-failed-container-linux-g)